# How to get the nrow of all dataframes in a custom environment

Tags: r

I want to get the nrow of all dataframes in an evironment I have created. How can I do this?

```
env <- new.env()
source("myscript.R", local = env)
listOfdf<-names(Filter(function(x) x, eapply(env, is.data.frame)))

 #Create the find and replace dataframe with the number representing each dataframe:
listOfdf<-data.frame(listOfdf,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This below does not work

```
lapply(listOfdf$listOfdf,function(x) nrow(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` and specify the `envir` as 'env'

```
sapply(mget(listOfdf, envir = env), nrow)
# df1 df2 
#  5  10
```

Here, 'listOfdf' is a `vector` of object identifiers, so we use `mget` to get the values stores in that identifiers located in the correct environment as a `list` and then loop through the `list` with `sapply` to get the number of rows (`nrow`)

#### data

```
env <- new.env()
env$df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
env$v1 <- 1:10
env$df2 <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:10])
listOfdf<-names(Filter(function(x) x, eapply(env, is.data.frame)))
```